# ¿Saber si una variable es de json en ionic?

Tags: ionic, typescript

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion el cual conecta al servidor y recibie una serie de datos en formato json, en el caso de que no existan datos disponibles retorna un texto, lo que quiero saber es como redireccionar el texto a una variable y los datos a otra

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
$.post('myurl.com/api/todo', {'parametros': {}}, function(data){

    try { 
        var obj = JSON.parse("OK"); 
        //login cuando es un json
    } 
    catch(error) { 
        console.log('Es un texto'); 
        //login cuando no hay datos
    }
});
```